# Hashtables and key order

Tags: powershell, sorting, hashtable, powershell-2.0

Is there a way to keep the order of keys in a hashtable as they were added? Like a push/pop mechanism.

Example:

```
$hashtable = @{}

$hashtable.Add("Switzerland", "Bern")
$hashtable.Add("Spain", "Madrid")
$hashtable.Add("Italy", "Rome")
$hashtable.Add("Germany", "Berlin")
$hashtable
```

I want to retain the order in which I've added the elements to the hashtable.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is no built-in solution in PowerShell V1 / V2. You will want to use the .NET
[`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary):

```
$order = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
$order.Add("Switzerland", "Bern")
$order.Add("Spain", "Madrid")
$order.Add("Italy", "Rome")
$order.Add("Germany", "Berlin")


PS> $order

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Switzerland                    Bern
Spain                          Madrid
Italy                          Rome
Germany                        Berlin
```

In PowerShell V3 you can cast to [ordered]:

```
PS> [ordered]@{"Switzerland"="Bern"; "Spain"="Madrid"; "Italy"="Rome"; "Germany"="Berlin"}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Switzerland                    Bern
Spain                          Madrid
Italy                          Rome
Germany                        Berlin
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I knew the PS v3 [ordered] but I must use PS 2.0

Comment: Thanks, what to say: strange implementation, I see no reason for that implementation as being the default. You need it unodered for raw speed? Do a custom class for that and let the base be, as most would expcet, ordered with the insert order.

Comment: Note that you also have to use this type (`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`) for the parameter if you want to [pass your ordered hash to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42568949/1028230). You cannot use a flavor of the `[ordered][hash]` shortcut as a param typing, and must use the full type. You can pass as a `[hash]` parameter, but you lose the ordering (since it's passed as the less specific extended `hash` type; more at [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42568949/1028230)), which is likely undesirable. 

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: casting to `[ordered]`.  I was able to do this when declaring a global variable as follows: `Set-Variable -Name MyOrderedHashtable -Scope global -Option AllScope -Value ([ordered]@{})`

Answer (score 10):

You can use an ordered dictionary instead:

Like this:

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
$list.Add("Switzerland", "Bern")
$list.Add("Spain", "Madrid")
$list.Add("Italy", "Rome")
$list.Add("Germany", "Berlin")
$list
```

Answer (score 7):

You can give one sequential key as you add elements:

```
$hashtable = @{}
$hashtable[$hashtable.count] = @("Switzerland", "Bern")
$hashtable[$hashtable.count] = @("Spain", "Madrid")
$hashtable[$hashtable.count] = @("Italy", "Rome")
$hashtable[$hashtable.count] = @("Germany", "Berlin")
$hashtable
```

Then, you can get elements sorted by the key:

```
echo "`nHashtable keeping the order as they were added"
foreach($item in $hashtable.getEnumerator() | Sort Key)
{
    $item
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell 1 way is to add a hashtable member to retain the add order. There is no need to use  System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary:

```
$Hash = New-Object PSObject                                       
$Hash | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name key1 -Value val1
$Hash | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name key2 -Value val2
$Hash | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name key3 -Value val3
```

Comment: But that's not a hashtable, it's a PSCustomObject. Not the same thing, even if you name the variable "$Hash". ;)  An OrderedDictionary functions just like a hashtable for all practical purposes that I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with older PowerShell versions you might consider this cmdlet:

```
Function Order-Keys {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][HashTable]$HashTable,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)][ScriptBlock]$Function,
        [Switch]$Descending
    )
    $Keys = $HashTable.Keys | ForEach {$_} # Copy HashTable + KeyCollection
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Keys.Count - 1; $i++) {
        For ($j = $i + 1; $j -lt $Keys.Count; $j++) {
            $a = $Keys[$i]
            $b = $Keys[$j]
            If ($Function -is "ScriptBlock") {
                $a = $HashTable[$a] | ForEach $Function
                $b = $HashTable[$b] | ForEach $Function
            }
            If ($Descending) {
                $Swap = $a -lt $b
            }
            Else
            {
                $Swap = $a -gt $b
            }
            If ($Swap) {
                $Keys[$i], $Keys[$j] = $Keys[$j], $Keys[$i]
            }
        }
    }
    Return $Keys
}
```

This cmdlet returns a list of keys ordered by the function definition:

Sort by name:

```
$HashTable | Order-Keys | ForEach {Write-Host $_ $HashTable[$_]}
Germany Berlin
Italy Rome
Spain Madrid
Switzerland Bern
```

Sort by value:

```
$HashTable | Order-Keys {$_} | ForEach {Write-Host $_ $HashTable[$_]}
Germany Berlin
Switzerland Bern
Spain Madrid
Italy Rome
```

You might also consider to nest hash tables:

```
$HashTable = @{
    Switzerland = @{Order = 1; Capital = "Berne"}
    Germany     = @{Order = 2; Capital = "Berlin"}
    Spain       = @{Order = 3; Capital = "Madrid"}
    Italy       = @{Order = 4; Capital = "Rome"}
}
```

E.g. sort by (hashed) order property and return the key (country):

```
$HashTable | Order-Keys {$_.Order} | ForEach {$_}
```

Or sort (descending) by the predefined capital:

```
$HashTable | Order-Keys {$_.Capital} -Descending | ForEach {$_}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple routine that works for me.

```
function sortedKeys([hashtable]$ht) {
  $out = @()
  foreach($k in $ht.keys) {
    $out += $k
  }
  [Array]::sort($out)
  return ,$out
}
```

and the call to use it

```
forEach($k in (& sortedKeys $ht)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: But the question was about keeping the order in which the hash was added to, not sorting by keys. How does this answer the question?

Comment: Peter, you are correct.  I was confused and thought Ordered dictionary was like a Java TreeMap not a LinkedHashMap. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

```
function global:sortDictionaryByKey([hashtable]$dictionary)
{
    return $dictionary.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property name;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!