# PowerShell hash table order

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The below script is running in a for-each loop and the output heading is not coming in the right order. I want the output order as I mentioned in the hash table. **I want the CSV table column heading in right order**, not the data inside the table.

Like 1.Machine_Name, 2.Ping_Status, 3.OS_Name

How can I solve this?

```
$Result = @{
            MACHINE_NAME     = "$_"
            PING_STATUS      = "MACHINE ONLINE"
            OS_NAME = "$OSNAME"
        }

$Details += New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
$Details | export-csv -Path $pathofcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Define "right order". A hashtable is not sorted a data structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Hashtables Key Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891044/powershell-hashtables-key-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the order, use [Select-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176955.aspx):

```
$Details | Select-Object MACHINE_NAME, PING_STATUS, OS_NAME | export-csv -Path $pathofcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 7):

Use an ordered hash table:

```
$Result = [ordered]@{             
            MACHINE_NAME     = "$_" 
            PING_STATUS      = "MACHINE ONLINE"
            OS_NAME = "$OSNAME"
        }

$Details += New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
$Details | export-csv -Path $pathofcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you  mjolinor... I already used  [ordered] key, but no luck.

Actually Machine_Name, Ping_status and OS_name is the heading of a csv. I want the heading column in right order, not the data inside file.

Comment: The column headings should be in the same order that the hash table enumerates.  If it's an ordered hash table, it should enumerate in the same order that the entries were defined.