# Passing an ordered hashtable to a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How can I go about passing an ordered hashtable to a function?

The following throws an error:

> The ordered attribute can be specified only on a hash literal node.

```
function doStuff {
    Param (
        [ordered]$theOrderedHashtable
    )
    $theOrderedHashtable
}

$datFileWithMinSizes  = [ordered]@{"FileA.DAT" = "4"; "FileB.DAT" = "5"; "FileC.DAT" = "91" ; "FileD.DAT" = "847"  }

doStuff -theOrderedHashtable $datFileWithMinSizes
```

The following does not maintain the correct order:

```
function doStuff {
    Param (
        [Hashtable]$theOrderedHashtable = [ordered]@{}
    )
    $theOrderedHashtable
}

$datFileWithMinSizes  = [ordered]@{"FileA.DAT" = "4"; "FileB.DAT" = "5"; "FileC.DAT" = "91" ; "FileD.DAT" = "847"  }

doStuff -theOrderedHashtable $datFileWithMinSizes
```

The only way I can currently get this to work is by not specifying the type as follows, but I want to specify the type:

```
function doStuff {
    Param (
        $theOrderedHashtable
    )
    $theOrderedHashtable
}

$datFileWithMinSizes  = [ordered]@{"FileA.DAT" = "4"; "FileB.DAT" = "5"; "FileC.DAT" = "91" ; "FileD.DAT" = "847"  }

doStuff -theOrderedHashtable $datFileWithMinSizes
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the full type name:

```
function Do-Stuff {
    param(
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$OrderedHashtable
    )
    $OrderedHashtable
}
```

To support both regular hashtables and ordered dictionaries, <strike>you'll have to use separate parameter sets:</strike> use the `[System.Collections.IDictionary]` interface, as [suggested by briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42569756/712649)

```
function Do-Stuff {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Ordered')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Ordered')]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$OrderedHashtable,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Hashtable')]
        [hashtable]$Hashtable
    )
    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Hashtable'){
        $OrderedHashtable = $Hashtable
    }
    $OrderedHashtable
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Mathias is right, but I wanted to point out that there is a way to accept both types without using parameter sets.

Both types implement the `IDictionary` interface, so you can strongly type your parameter with the interface instead, and then any type (including custom types that you create or don't know about yet) which implements the interface will be accepted:

```
function Do-Stuff {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Ordered')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Ordered')]
        [System.Collections.IDictionary]$Dictionary
    )
    $Dictionary.GetType().FullName
}
```

This would accept both:

> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> do-stuff @{}
> System.Collections.Hashtable
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> do-stuff ([ordered]@{})
> System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
> ```

Similarly, if you want to *only accept* an ordered dictionary (but not *just* the specific `OrderedDictionary` type), you can use the `IOrderedDictionary` interface, which is implemented by the aforementioned type, but not by `[hashtable]`:

```
function Do-Stuff {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Ordered')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='Ordered')]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary]$Dictionary

    )

    $Dictionary.GetType().FullName
}
```

Then:

> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> do-stuff ([ordered]@{})
> System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> do-stuff @{}
> Do-Stuff : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Dictionary'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type 
> "System.Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary".
> At line:1 char:10
> + do-stuff @{}
> +          ~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Do-Stuff], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Do-Stuff
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Just **to *complement* the existing, helpful answers**:

What the error message

> The ordered attribute can be specified only on a hash literal node.

is trying to tell you:

**`[ordered]` is *syntactic sugar*, and it only works before hashtable *literals* (`@{ ... }`).**

You can determine the actual type of an ordered hashtable literal as follows:

```
PS> ([ordered] @{ foo = 1 }).GetType().FullName
System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

That is, an ordered hashtable literal in PowerShell is an instance of type [`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This is very helpful. I had previously tried [OrderedDictionary] also, which was retrieved from ([ordered] @{ foo = 1 }).GetType().Name but this does not work. ([ordered] @{ foo = 1 }).GetType().FullName gets he full Type name which does work.