# Passing Ordered hash table to a script block breaks the order

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to collect some info from remote hosts in form of a CSV string. I need the values to be returned in particular order to accumulate them in one CSV file.

I use ordered hash table to keep keys in particular order, but when I pass it to a remote host the order gets broken.

Is there a way to preserve the order?

```
$ordered_hash = [ordered]@{"a" = 1; "b" = 2; "c" = 3}
$ordered_hash
$scriptblock = {
param ($hash)
$hash
} 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList ([hashtable]$ordered_hash)
```

Returns:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
a                              1                                                                                                                                         
b                              2                                                                                                                                         
c                              3                                                                                                                                         
c                              3                                                                                                                                         
b                              2                                                                                                                                         
a                              1
```

Comment: A possible workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14891044/56778

Comment: `-ArgumentList ([hashtable]$ordered_hash)` -> `-ArgumentList $ordered_hash`?

Comment: It is know issue with PowerShell serialization system: `$s = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]; $o = [ordered]@{}; $o.GetType().FullName; $s::Deserialize($s::Serialize($o)).GetType().FullName`

Comment: I tried to pass an argument without [hashtable] definition, but that made no difference, The order got lost .

Comment: @PapaSmurf If you want to notify someone of your comment, then you should use `@UserName` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a hash table using `[ordered]` attribute, in fact it creates a `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`.

When passing it to a parameter of `HashTable` type, it converts the `OrderedDictionary` to `HashTable` which is no more ordered.

To keep the order, you can use either of following options:

- Remove the type from parameters of the script block to prevent a type change. This way it will use the original type which is use `OrderedDictionary`.

*Or*

- Use `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` type of the parameter of the script block.

Comment: I tried both options with the example which you shared and both of them work properly. Let me know if you have any question about the answer ...

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got the same result.
$ordered_hash = [ordered]@{"a" = 1; "b" = 2; "c" = 3}
$ordered_hash
$scriptblock = {
param ($hash)
$hash
} 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList ([System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$ordered_hash)