# PowerShell Hashtable to JSON without Quotes

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am trying to create a hash table to use as the body to POST to a rest API.  The documentation listed the format for the JSON should be in, but having some formatting problems when using `ConvertTo-Json` in PowerShell.

Some of the values in JSON cannot be in quotes, and some need to be in quotes.  I can get static values to output without quotes using `$($value)`, but this does not work the same when the value is an existing variable.

`$($variable)` does not remove quotes on variables from JSON output like it does on static values.

Current hash table:

```bsh
$starttime = "1565787600000" #Converted to EPOCH
$endtime = "1597410000000" #Converted to EPOCH

$body = @{}
$body.documentName = "Test.txt"
$body.accessList = @{}
$body.accessList.email = "test@email.com"
$body.accessList.startTime = $starttime  # <--cannot have quotes in json
$body.accessList.endTime = $endtime      # <--cannot have quotes in json

$bodyJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2
```

Output:

```json
{
    "documentName":  "Test.txt",
    "accessList":  {
                       "email":  "test@email.com",
                       "endTime":  "1597410000000", <--cannot have quotes
                       "startTime":  "1565787600000" <--cannot have quotes
                   }
}
```

Desired output:

```bsh
{
    "documentName":  "Test.txt",
    "accessList":  {
                       "email":  "test@email.com",
                       "endTime":  1597410000000, <--no quotes
                       "startTime":  1565787600000 <--no quotes
                   }
}
```

Comment: DateTime is not a type in JSON.. it would be an error to not have quotes.

Comment: I just checked the order on PSv5.1/6.2.2 on Win10/Ubuntu/MacOS pasting the very same code and ***every*** instance had a different order - but who cares / what does it matter for a primarily m2m format?

Comment: The actual value will be in EPOCH, but either way, I'm looking to see how to remove the quotes regardless of the value.  The above code is just an example.

Comment: For the order see: [Hashtables and key order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891153/1701026)

Comment: Your change from a string to an int totally changed the issue and makes your title now a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POSIX timestamps are defined as strings. You need to either define them as integers

```
$starttime = 1565787600000
$endtime = 1597410000000
```

or turn the strings into integers before converting your data structure to JSON.

```
$starttime = "1565787600000"
$endtime = "1597410000000"
...
$body.accessList.startTime = [int64]$starttime
$body.accessList.endTime = [int64]$endtime
```